# Navigation Component: deep link won't open in app until a user checks an address as supported one in settings of app

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-12, android-deep-link, android-13

So I have implemented the deep link logic like this with [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link):

nav_graph.xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordChangeFragment"
    android:name="......ForgotPasswordChangeFragment" >
    <argument
        android:name="token"
        app:argType="string" />
    <deepLink app:uri="https://example.com/create-new-password/{token}" />
</fragment>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    
    <nav-graph android:value="@navigation/nav_graph_main" />

</activity>
```

But the link `https://example.com/create-new-password/24c37747e3a451e60c0c61c06b36eee7` opens only in browser apps (for Android 12+)

When I allow `example.com` as supported web address in the device system settings about app ("App info") then it works fine

[image]

[image]

[image]

But users are not going to do such things...

Should add some other permissions somehow for the address or deep link? What else do I miss?

**UPDATE**

I checked this https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

But how can I add `android:autoVerify` when I use Navigation Component and graph.xml?

Comment: The docs you linked to indicate that you can add `android:autoVerify` to your `deepLink`

Comment: @ianhanniballake add where? the doc says nothing about navigation component and its graph. You can add it to intent filter (at android manifest) manually if you don't use navigation component, in this case the doc is ok

Comment: The docs is not clear enough - you should add the `autoVerify` as an attribute of `<deepLink/>` inside nav graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [page you've linked to](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit), the visual Navigation Editor allows you to set this when building your deep link:

> (optional) Check **Auto Verify** to require Google to verify that you are the owner of the URI.

You can manually add this to your XML as well (which is all the visual editor is going to do for you):

```
<deepLink
    app:uri="https://example.com/create-new-password/{token}"
    android:autoVerify="true" />
```

This will automatically add that flag to the generated intent filters in your manifest.